# How to do countifs in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, countif, multiple-conditions

I want to do countif in PowerBI (Example: count of total item with condition #1: having transaction of 2 or more, condition #2: year)

I have sample data comprised of PO (transaction) #, item #, date (year), item description, ship to location.

I can achieve the result through Excel - Pivot a matrix table of rows of items, columns of year and the value is count of PO/transactions. A separate table on the side is utilized to count the total item within Column (Years) that has transaction count > 2.

I can't figure out what DAX to use in PowerBI to achieve the same thing as I could with Excel:

[image]

Sample of transaction counts:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually `COUNTIFS` in Excel are implemented by use of `CALCULATE(<expression>,<filter1>,<filter2>…)` in Power BI, for example:

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Column1]), FILTER(Table1, Table1[Column1] < Table1[Column2]))
```

Read more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax).